# Setting Terminal tab names in OS X and using vim

Tags: bash, terminal, vim, osx, window-title

I regularly ssh into a Linux cluster from an OS X (El Capitan) Terminal, sometimes with multiple Terminal tabs. I use bash and vim.

I'd like to do the following:

- while ssh'd, set the Terminal tab title to the current working directory using `` PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\e]1;"`basename $PWD`"\a"' ``
- while using vim, set the Terminal tab title to "vim — FILENAME"

Here are my problems:

- If I do `let &titlestring = "vim — " . expand("%:t")` and `set title` in .vimrc, it changes the Terminal *window* title, not the tab title. If I do not separately set the tab title (parameter 1), the tab title mirrors the window title (parameter 2), but as soon as I set the tab title, it "decouples" from the window title.
- If I run an external command in **.vimrc** with `:!`, I get a "Press ENTER" dialog that's annoying.
- If I use `:silent !` in **.vimrc**, my Terminal prompt ends up at the bottom of the screen after exiting vim. I *really* don't want to muck around with saving the prompt position and resetting it every time I want to use vim.
- If I define in my **.bashrc** the following function:

  ```
  function vim
  {
      printf "\e]1;"`basename "$1"`"\a"
      vim "$1"
  }
  ```

  then my terminal *crashes* upon calling `vim` from the command line. Calling the function `vvim` instead works, but I don't want to type `vvim` forever. I want to alias `vim`.

So I seem stuck. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The function `vim` calls the function `vim` calls the function `vim`, etc. Replace `vim "$1"` with `command vim "$1"` to avoid this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've solved my own problem. I fail programming 101.

By defining vim as a function and then calling vim, I set up an infinite recursive loop. No wonder my terminal crashed. I need to call the "real" vim, the actual executable. This did the trick:

```
function vim
{
    printf "\e]1;"`basename "$1"`"\a"
    /usr/bin/vim "$1"
}
```

Comment: Much better to follow the advice of @thrig and use the Bash built-in `command` in front of `vim` in order to use the standard lookup mechanisms instead of hardcoding the path.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work if you change the file after starting `vim`. E.g. with the `Ctrl+p` plugin.